# Will the Pi boot to exFAT partitions?

Tags: boot, exfat

It's my understanding that originally the Pi's would not boot to exFAT.  Also, they would not boot to USB or PXE boot, but the latter two have been enabled as time goes on.  The [official page for SDXC](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/sdxc_formatting.md) cards has no date or model-specific information, so I have no idea if it's outdated, or things have changed with newer boards, or still relevent.  [This Github page](https://github.com/raspberrypi/noobs/issues/540) has a lot of chatter and is over a year old, so it's possible that a fix or change has been rolled in to the codebase.  Skimming through it, I don't see anything that says one way or the other about it.

Are the Raspberry Pi's able to boot to anything other than FAT, FAT16, and FAT32, for example exFAT?  Does that depend on which model you're working on?

Comment: Just curious: Why does that matter? The boot partition of the Pi is usually very small (100MB or so), so that FAT32 is more than good enough. And the OS partition uses a linux file system (ext4 I think) which can have an arbitrary size.

Comment: Full boot details are documented by RPF at https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/bootmodes/README.md so I'm voting a close.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because boot capabilities are well documented.

Comment: @Andyroo you are part of the problem, now a caricature, with SE sites like this.  Clearly it's not that well documented if I couldn't find it in a few hours of searching.  ON TOP OF WHICH, that link you sent me..... HAS NOTHING ABOUT SD CARD FORMATS ***SMDH***  Also, you glossed over the whole lack of a date thing on all the official documentation.

Comment: What is the problem to just try it? Do you know how to format a partition with the exFAT file system? I agree with @Andyroo and have also voted to close.

Comment: That something has external documentation **is not a reason for us to close a question**, otherwise (very seriously) something like 95% of the questions here and on SE as a whole should be closed, because in every case there is *someone somewhere* who could point to some documentation somewhere and say, "See it is right here in this documentation".   What on Earth does https://math.stackexchange.com/ exist for?  Isn't math exhaustively and extensively documented already? *If you think a question is lazy, poorly researched, irrelevant, etc. **vote it down**.*

Comment: @goldilocks Sorry but first part of https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask states research.  The current abilities are well documented and that's all it supports.  If it's left open it just floats around like lots of the questions here.  TBH, I'll quit for a month or two - this is such an odd two faced place I obviously do not fit or see eye to eye with most folk.

Comment: @Andyroo My point is there is a mechanism to deal with illegitimate questions, even if they are brilliantly researched and composed (*closed* because, eg., has nothing to do with the Pi) which is distinct from how to deal with legitimate but poorly researched questions (*downvote* -- buzz your mouse over the downvote arrow and read the tooltip there).  But the boundary is of course murky.  I apologize for being bombastic.  Do take a break if you are starting to feel more negative than positive about stuff here, but don't give up, you have much to offer and it is appreciated.